# package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: json, node.js, express, npm

I used http://jsonlint.com/ to check the syntax for this package.json file

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": “4.6.1"
  }
}
```

it returns the error

```
Parse error on line 7:
...        "express": “4.6.1"  }}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

not sure what is wrong with this. terminal is throwing the error for using npm install

```
"Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript."
```

Comment: Note: If you are try running the npm build using azure devops pipeline, make sure on git checkout the files are not under git lfs. If the `json` files are in git lfs, then follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838104/1176573).

Comment: `“` is not the same character as `"`

Comment: In my case it was a missing `,` at the end of the line (after I sorted the lines)

Answer (score 36):

Just type `npm cache clean` on prompt and all the things must to work again.

Comment: It appears that some of us are getting this error without any 'curly' quotes. In this case, this answer works a treat... I like the fact that NPM declares 'This is not a bug in NPM'  Lol. Clearly a bug in npm.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. :)

Comment: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify` instead

Comment: update as it is relevant on the newer version but wasnt at the time of the above posting.

As of npm@5 you have to do a 
   ```npm cache clean --force```

Answer (score 26):

package.json file should not be empty.

If you have empty package json file just add {}.

and try again.

[image]

Comment: This is the **only** answer that solved my issue. I was getting so fed up of reading the `npm cache clean` answers. Thank you!!

Comment: This solved my issue as well. "npm cache clean" had zero effect for me.

Answer (score 22):

You have curly quotes before the 4 - `“4.6.1"`. Change that to a regular quote character and it'll pass.

Answer (score 7):

It's a general syntax error message. Received the same error when a comma was missing in my code. Just running npm cache clean won't work if there's a glitch in the code. I added the missing comma and the program ran to success.

Answer (score 1):

I had got this same type of error. The answer, `npm cache clean` once solved my question but I got stuck for another reason while installing `express.js`

1. There is a short suggestion that I learned from this segment is to put just `{}` in the `package.json` file. I didn't try that but I believe that would work.
2. I have did another work.

I typed `npm init` and then put some description on this file like **project name, author, version** etc. Then I have terminated. And that made my file the real `JSON Format.` And I had my problem solved.

Comment: npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues

Answer (score 1):

Go on google and search for a json code online editor and copy that your package.json code and paste it there, the json editor should flag any syntax errors. I got the same error and for me it was just syntax and that worked for me.

Try this json code editor: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.nuxuti

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong quotation marks in line 7.

This version will do the job. ;-)

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.6.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. The answer you posted on a 6 yr old question, is similar to the other existing answers
. Better to look for new questions to answer and contribute to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `npm cache clean` on prompt and all the things must to work again.

other option is to check if you did not comment any thing in your JSON code, because JSON does not support comments.

Comment: npm cache clean does not work, npm ERR!   If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm ERR!   with --force.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I found out that in package.json I added a trailing comma in an object ("scripts" in my case). By removing it, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I would suggest looking into the code once because generally, it's due to some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my JSON was an empty description, so instead

```
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "", <--- this was the problem
    "main": "server.js",
```

I've used

```
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Some description",
    "main": "server.js",
```

and everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

All of answers didnt solve my problem.  I got almost same error. I solved with different way.

Especially if you are using VScode, firstly, you must save your changes. You can write "npm run deploy" after that. It worked...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35725485)